# Does object get destroyed when session expires?

Tags: php, session-variables, session-timeout

In my PHP application I have defined a User_class (with some properties and some methods including `__construct()` and `__destruct()` ). I've instantiated an object from this class and in order to use it's credentials , I have stored this object in `$_SESSION` super global using serialize method . the `_destruct()` method runs some private methods including log_out . 
My question is , does expiration of the session destroy the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear answer: No, it doesn't.

The object is stored in the session as a String, representing the current values of all properties, but not (!) any methods, con- or destructors.

When the session expires and garbage collection is active, the remaining sessions in the session store are just deleted.

In order to log a user out explicitly once the session is expired, you need to register your own session handler.

BTW: in order to store an object in the `$_SESSION` var, it's not necessary to serialze it explicitly. Just `$_SESSION['obj'] = $myObj;` is sufficient - and speeds up things tremendously.

Comment: thank you for helping .since I can't save the object straight into the session (tried it but apparently it doesn't work) , is there any way to call the destruct function upon session expiration.

Comment: @user3112162 1st you should obviously take care about that "doesn't work" with storing your object to the session. What error messages? 2nd: registering your own session handler is the only option.